# Unable to load SiteMinder agent configuration object

Tags: apache, siteminder

When I tried to access web I face this error in error log file.

> [Error] SiteMinder Agent
>           Unable to load SiteMinder agent configuration object.
>           Check that you are using the right agent configuration object and that it exists in your policy server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an ACO object corruption.